# How do I get the current validator of a mongo collection?

Tags: mongodb

How do I get the current validator of a mongo collection?

Or is there no way, and I just need to overwrite it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get it with the [db.getCollectionInfos()](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/method/db.getCollectionInfos/#db.getCollectionInfos) method.

**Example:**

Create a collection in an empty database:

```
db.createCollection( "contacts",
   {
      validator: { $or:
         [
            { phone: { $type: "string" } },
            { email: { $regex: /@mongodb\.com$/ } },
            { status: { $in: [ "Unknown", "Incomplete" ] } }
         ]
      },
      validationAction: "warn"
   }
)
```

> { "ok" : 1 }

Run the command:

```
db.getCollectionInfos()[0].options.validator
```

Result:

```
{
  "$or" : [
    {
      "phone": {
        "$type": "string"
      }
    },
    {
      "email": {
        "$regex": /@mongodb\.com$/
      }
    },
    {
      "status": {
        "$in": [
          "Unknown",
          "Incomplete"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The validator is found as an object in the options object.